# Angular 2/4 template cache-busting is not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, browser-cache, angular-components, angular-template

We have a Problem with our Angular 4 application regarding cache-busting.
It seems, that old template-files are cached when we release new versions (Ctrl + F5 solves the problem).

We use angular-cli (--prod) to build our application which should handle cache-busting when new versions are released. The compiled js-file-names contain a hash-number for every version so that files won't be cached. And the html should be included in the javascript-files. Still old template-stuff seems to be cached.

One possible solution might be this one here: [How to prevent Browser cache on Angular 2 site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647810/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-on-angular-2-site)
Why should this change anything as not the template but js-files are requested?
What's the best solution for this problem`?

Comment: Did you make sure that it's not the main page (index.html) itself that is cached ?

Comment: Actually this might be the problem. Is it good practise to use the cache-control meta-tag for this? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/3584607)

Comment: Would this also effetc image-caching, javascript...?

Comment: It depends on the browser and the cache meta added by your web server (apache, nginx)

Comment: I used a non-trivial solution, but one that eliminates all type cache issues in angular 6 (browser, cdn, proxies/isp cache) see (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538027/1544054)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set cache-expires header for the index.html file in our amazon S3-bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3