# Browser History/cache Clean through c# code

Tags: c#, browser, browser-cache

My question is ,
Can i clean **Browser cache/history** through code(c#).
because, Browser always stored previous **angular/css**.
Everytime, we have to clear manually(By **Cntrl+Shift+Del**).
Is there any **C#** Code to clear history with button click.
  *Thank you*.

Comment: You need to fix the problem, not automate cache clearing.

Comment: [You want to investigate what is called cache busting](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/)

Comment: @DavidG, you mean ,there is no way through coding..

Comment: are you using asp.net core?

Comment: @rjs123431 only .net

Comment: No, I mean use cache busting e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647810/how-to-prevent-browser-cache-on-angular-2-site

Comment: you mention about C#, angular/css, it means this is a web application .net framework, it that correct?

Comment: yes @rjs123431.

Comment: okay, so you don't need to clear the cache, possible solution in .net mvc is to append a version of the js and css files

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is about the css and js files are cached in the browser.

Please look at the default template of Asp Mvc Application.

`_Layout.cshtml` should have this at the bottom

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

In `BundleConfig.cs`, you need to add this at the bottom of the `RegisterBundles` method

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

You should see the source of the web page the scripts have some extra version

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=2u0aRenDpYxArEyILB59ETSCA2cfQkSMlxb6jbMBqf81"></script>
```

In this way, whenever you have changes in your js or css files, version will change so browser will treat this as another file instead of the previous cached version of js or css files.

In Asp.Net Core MVC, it is much easy using `asp-append-version`

```
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```